# It's not accepting the apiKey in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, authentication

I'm not able to do Authorization here. It's not taking the apiKey.

```
  getTrendingWallpaper() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?per_page=15&page=1',
        headers: {"Authorization": apiKey});
  }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your api key is valid in, say, Postman?

Comment: you can print out apiKey to see the result don't forget that it might be  "Bearer $apiKey" instead

Comment: @RichardHeap yes, It's valid